# How to change change / to - in yii2 url for specific action

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

I'm rewriting wordpress site to yii2.
and I have to keep previous posts urls for some reasons!
They are somethings like that

```
https://example.com/blog-thenameofpost
```

So I created a Blog controller and I have this link in this way

```
https://example.com/blog/view?id=thenameofpost
```

I don't know how can I write a urlManager rule for doing that.
I just add this rules

```
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

and now  this link 
`https://example.com/blog/view?id=thenameofpost`
 opens with something like it:
`https://example.com/blog/thenameofpost`

Are there any rules to open link with some thing like it `https://example.com/blog/thenameofpost` ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the "blog/" part from the URL?

Comment: yes just for an action or an controller. removing that might help me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a rule for `https://example.com/blog-thenameofpost` you could add the following rule.

```
'blog-<id>' => 'blog/view',
```

The left part is what you will actually see in your address bar. You can use `< >` to indicate a parameter. So this rule will match anything that starts with `blog-` and then consider the part after that as the `id` param. The right part is where this request should be routed to. So this request will end up in the `BlogController` and call `actionView($id)`, where `$id` will be set to the `<id>` part; *thenameofpost* in the case of the example URL.

The rule for `https://example.com/blog/thenameofpost` would be

```
'blog/<id>' => 'blog/view'
```

Additional info:
In the param part (left side) you can add additional info for matching the param. So `<id:\d+>` will only match digits, because of de `\d+` part. For more info read the docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$rules-detail

Comment: I guess you should use a <url> parameter from your database instead of the id, and after that in your actionView load the model from the url field.